# Use Custom Submit Button on Blazor EditForm

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have created a custom button component, which disables itself and shows a busy spinner whilst busy:

```
bool IsBusy;
async Task HandleClickAsync()
{
    if (IsBusy) return;
    IsBusy = true;
    try
    {
        await OnClick.InvokeAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

IsBusy value is queried in the html to add an appropriate Css class to disable and show the spinner.  This prevents duplicate events whilst processing.  This button would be used for API calls, including getting data and form submission.

Works a dream for retrieving data from an API.

The issue is that when I use it as a 'submit' button on a form, it is the EditForm OnValidSubmit event that processes the click, not my HandleClickAsync() handler.

So, I guess what I'm after is being able to place the button within an EditForm, not assign a type of "submit", and then capture the click and invoke the OnValidSubmit event on the parent EditForm manually.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have taken is:

- Remove "OnValidSubmit" from EditForm
- Add an "OnValidSubmit" event to the custom command button

Then used this in the custom command

```
[CascadingParameter] public EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

async Task HandleClickAsync()
{
    if (EditContext.Validate())
    {
        await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

And then handle the OnValidSubmit event from the button, instead of the EditForm.  Seems to work, but happy to hear of any smarter solution (am not sure if there are any gotchas using this approach).